# How to get connection string from appsettings.json inside custom filter in .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a controller EBisUserController which contains a public property ConnectionString obtained from `appsettings.json` through dependency injection. The controller has an attribute filter 'EBisUserAuthResourceFilter' requiring use of the property ConnectionString found in the controller.  What is the most performant method to access ConnectionString.  I have a working example of what I want, but know this is not the correct way of doing this as it must open and read the file for each transaction.

```
public class EBisUserAuthResourceFilter : Attribute, IResourceFilter { 

    private string _connectionString;

    public EBisUserAuthResourceFilter() {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        _connectionString= builder.Build().GetValue<string>("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"); //this property exists as property of controller through DI, how can we access it?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency injection is possible in filters as well.

Here is a simple way to get connection string

```
public class EBisUserAuthResourceFilter : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public EBisUserAuthResourceFilter(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.connectionString = configuration
                   .GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value;
    }
    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
        // use this.connectionString
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        // use this.connectionString
    }
}
```

Now you can use this filter

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(EBisUserAuthResourceFilter))]
public class HomeController : Controller
{  }
```

You also need to add this Filter to the service collection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped<EBisUserAuthResourceFilter>();

   // your existing code to add other services
}
```

Another solution is to have a class representing the structure of the content of `AppSettings.json` file or a sub section and load that in your Startup classes' `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.Configure<SiteSettings>(Configuration);
```

and now you can inject `IOptions<SiteSettings>` and use the needed property values. I prefer this as it is **less magic strings** in my code.

Comment: The top example, which is preferrable to me since the appsettings.json will probably me modified often for new development worked with the following modification: in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs I had to add: `services.AddTransient<EBisUserAuthResourceFilter>();`

Comment: Yes. You need to do that for the filter to be available